# Chrome developer tools console - What are the brackets around some logged objects?

Tags: google-chrome, logging, console

I'm logging some object, arrays, strings to Chrome console in this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RkXqg/

Some of the console objects have brackets [] around them .. others don't..

What do the brackets mean?  ...does a console object look
different if its detached from DOM?  etc... can't find doc on this..

Thanks much..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will return an array for all matches to the selector you pass into the $ function. If you want to access the DOM object itself, access that index from the array: $('selector')[0]